# c# Bitmap.GetHbitmap() changes bitcount of image

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm using [**Bitmap.GetHbitmap**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.gethbitmap?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) for passing image to C++ dll from c# like below.

```
Bitmap img = Bitmap.FromFile(PATH);   // this is 24bppRGB bitmap.
IntPtr hBit = img.GetHbitmap();       // Make hbitmap for c++ dll.
```

Here's problem:

```
Bitmap temp = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBit); // It changes to 32bppRGB.
```

I need 24bpp bitmap for c++ dll methods, but **GetHbitmap()** changes the bitcount.

How can I make a 24bpp `HBITMAP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Version

Use [**Bitmap.LockBits**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) and [**CreateDIBSection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection) to manually create your desired `HBITMAP`.

### Long Version

[**Bitmap.GetHBITMAP**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-gethbitmap) will [always](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/423f6531-e23c-4a9c-a1c5-3b142791d707/how-to-create-8-bit-hbitmap-from-bitmap?forum=csharpgeneral) return a 32bpp `HBITMAP`; no matter what the format of the image you actually loaded is. This is because it is the format the image is internally stored as. You will need to manually create an `HBITMAP` yourself.

You can use **CreateDIBSection** to create your own 24bpp bitmap. The function returns a pointer where you can place the raw pixel data.

Fortunately GDI+ lets you obtain pixel data in whatever format you want, by calling **LockBits** and specifying the pixel format you want (i.e. `PixelFormat24bppRGB`). Then you can just copy the pixel data. There may be issues with `-Stride`, and top-down or bottom-up bitmaps.

1. Define a `BITMAPINFO` for the bitmap we want to create:

   ```
   BITMAPINFO bm;
   bm.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
   bm.bmiHeader.biWidth = img.Width;
   bm.bmiHeader.biHeight = -img.Height;      // oriented top-down
   bm.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
   bm.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;             // 24bpp
   bm.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;      // no compression
   bm.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;             // let Windows determine size
   bm.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;         // Not used by CreateDIBSection
   bm.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;         // Not used by CreateDIBSection
   ```
2. Create a DIBSection based on the bitmap info, and get the buffer where we place our pixel data

   ```
   Pointer dibPixels; //will receive a point where we can stuff our pixel data
   HBITMAP bmp = CreateDIBSection(0, bmInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, out dibPixels, 0, 0);
   ```
3. Use [**Bitmap.LockBits**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-lockbits) to obtain a pointer to pixel data in the format you want:

   ```
   BitmapData bitmapData = img.LockBits(
         img.Bounds,          //get entire image
         ImageLockModeRead,
         PixelFormat24bppRGB  //we want the pixel data in 24bpp format
         );
   ```
4. Copy pixel data from our `bitmapData` source image into the pixel buffer returned by **CreateDIBSectin**:

   ```
   int stride = bitmapData.Stride;
   int bufferSize = stride * bmData.Height; 
   CopyMemory(bitmapData.Scan0, dibPixels, bufferSize);
   ```
5. Unlock the bits:

   ```
   img.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
   ```

Now you have your `HBITMAP` bitmap ready to pass to your dll seven years later.

## Bonus Reading

- The Supercomputing Blog: [Using LockBits in GDI+](http://supercomputingblog.com/graphics/using-lockbits-in-gdi/) <sup>[*archive*](https://archive.ph/wip/cqYT3)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for kindly answering a question from several years ago that had been forgotten. I was really curious at the time, and even now, it feels great to finally find an answer :)